# Webform 8.x-5.0-RC3 can't set custom settings

Tags: 8, webforms

Here is my problem. I have a drupal website I'm working on where I've got webform with custom settings (such as checklist with custom elements and some others). I was on 5.0-beta24 and everything was fine. I saw that an update to the RC3 was available so I tried to see if there was any breaking change. And it seems that my custom settings are no longer saved.

What is the breaking change, and is there a solution so I can still define my custom settings / another way to do it ?

You can find below my current function to alter the settings form and add my custom's one.

```
<?php
function mymodule__form_webform_settings_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $settings = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->getSettings();

  $form['general_settings']['description']['#title'] = t("Subtitle");
  $form['general_settings']['description']['#type'] = 'textfield';

  $form['form_settings_categories'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => 'Catégories',
    '#open' => TRUE,
    '#input' => FALSE,
  ];

  $form['form_settings_categories']['categories'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => \Drupal\avantages\Services\PopulationsService::getPopulationList(),
    '#title' => t('Catégories'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['categories'] ?? ['test'],
    '#required' => FALSE,
  ];

}
```

Edit :

After some research, it seems (but I can be wrong) that the line that cause trouble is this one

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function setSettings(array $settings) {
    // Always apply the default settings.
    $this->settings += static::getDefaultSettings();
    // Now apply new settings.
    foreach ($settings as $name => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->settings)) {
      $this->settings[$name] = $value;
    }
  }

  return $this;
}
```

As my custom setting is not is getDefaultSettings, I can't save it.

Is there any new way to save custom settings ?

Thanks

Comment: You're using Drupal 5?!

Comment: Oops sorry, typo. I'm using Webform 5 on Drupal 8

Comment: I updated the title to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. Webform implement [ThirdPartySettingsInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Config%21Entity%21ThirdPartySettingsInterface.php/interface/ThirdPartySettingsInterface/8.5.x) so I can edit my form_alter function to do the following :

```
// Because hidden by default.
$form["third_party_settings"]["#access"] = true; 
$form['third_party_settings']['quizzes']['details_categories'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => 'Catégories',
    '#open' => true,
    '#input' => false,
  ];

  $form['third_party_settings']['quizzes']['details_categories']['categories'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => \Drupal\avantages\Services\PopulationsService::getPopulationList(),
    '#title' => t('Catégories'),
    '#default_value' => "",
    '#required' => false,
  ];
```

And to access my data, within the Webform entity :

```
$webform->getThirdPartySetting("quizzes", "categories");
```